# Firebase SSO Auth not working in Facebook In App Browser

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase Auth and provide Google and Facebook login on our site.

We are a publisher and most of our stories are published as Instant Articles. However, some articles are locked and requires subscribers to login to read the full content.

This works in a normal browser, but when opening a non-IA link in FB In App Browser, the login popup appears but remains blank, and does not close.

Users are not signed in and can't login.

We are using:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
```

I was wondering if there are any ways besides the signInWithPopup that can help us achieve this?

Thx.

Comment: Does `signInWithRedirect` work?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Yes, it works with signInWithRedirect

Answer (score 3):

As @bojeil mentioned,

use firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider) instead.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work either (redirecting to empty page). Has anyone succeeded to make it work?

Comment: It worked for me. You can clear the cache data of facebook browser. signInWithPopup was the issue